# define types of children as a props without using types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am getting error in this code

```js
function GlobalProvider({children : React.ReactNode}){

}
```

this code has the following error

> `children` not define

But when I use types it works fine

```js
type Prop = {children : React.ReactNode} //this works fine
function GlobalProvider({children}:Prop){

}
```

although my code works fine now , but I'm curious to know that can I define types without help of `type` to `interface`

thanks

Comment: `function GlobalProvider({ children } : {children : React.ReactNode})` is what you want, the `{children}` is the destructuring expression, and `{children : React.ReactNode}` is the type of the parameter

Comment: Thanks this works for me